# Apache Solr sort based on score and fieldn values

Tags: apache, sorting, search, solr, field

I used the following request

`http://localhost:8983/solr/test6/select?q=*:*&sort=product(score,hits)%20desc`

to sort results based on their relevancy score as determined by Apache Solr multiplied by a field called hits (integers).

However, I receive the following error message:

```
{   "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "sort":"product(score,hits) desc"}},   "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: product(score,hits)",
    "code":400}}
```

Why is it that sort cannot correctly input the function value when:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/test6/select?q=*:*&sort=score%20desc`

`http://localhost:8983/solr/test6/select?q=*:*&sort=hits%20desc`

work when a function isn't applied?

**NOTE**: `http://localhost:8983/solr/test6/select?q=*:*&sort=product(hits,2)%20desc` where I added the product() function also returns the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

The `score` value isn't really a field - so you can't use a function to manipulate it in the sort clause.

Instead you can use a multiplicative boost through `boost` (if you're using edismax) to achieve what you want: `&boost=hits`. You might want to use `log(hits)` or something similar (`recip` for example) instead to avoid large differences in score for just small changes in the number of hits.